# How can I make amsthm and cleveref to work with htlatex?

Tags: cleveref, amsthm, htlatex

I have the following `test.tex` document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{rmk}
.
\end{rmk}
\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex` and `latex`, everything works fine:

```
D:\Documents\GitHub\book>latex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\ifxetex.sty)
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hdvips.def"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pdfmark.def"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty")))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty")
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\cleveref.sty)
No file test.aux.
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

[1] (D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 2332 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

D:\Documents\GitHub\book>pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\ifxetex.sty)
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty")
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\cleveref.sty) (D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.aux)
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.out) (D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.out)
[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.aux) )<D:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><D:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><D:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 28695 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

D:\Documents\GitHub\book>
```

However, with `htlatex`, I get errors:

```
D:\Documents\GitHub\book>htlatex test.tex

D:\Documents\GitHub\book>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\
def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafte
r\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#
1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HC
ode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentsty
le[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode .a.
b.c.\input  test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tex
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\ifxetex.sty)
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"

Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document,
(auxhook)                using \AtBeginDocument instead.

) ("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty")

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver: htex4ht.

("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\htex4ht.def")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty")
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\cleveref.sty)
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) ("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvipsnam.def"))
--- needs --- tex4ht test ---
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tmp)
l.1437 --- TeX4ht warning --- No file test.xref ---
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\hyperref.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\nameref.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\pd1enc.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\url.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amsthm.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\color.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\dvips.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\dvipsnam.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvipsnam.def")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
No file test.aux.
! Argument of \eorem:syle has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.8 \begin{rmk}

?
```

What went wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: i'm not sure what's different using `\newaliascnt{rmk}{thm}` that wouldn't be provided by `amsthm`'s `\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}`?  (i also suggest using a different `\theoremstyle`, either `remark` or `definition`, so the text isn't set in italic.)

Comment: Indeed, `\newaliascnt{rmk}{thm}` is not necessary to produce the error.  I've updated the question statement.  The `\theoremstyle` is, indeed, changed in my source material, but I cut out that command for my minimal (non-)working example.

Comment: i'm not familiar with `htlatex`, but the error message makes me wonder if there's something in the interaction between `amsthm` and `cleveref` that's triggering it.  what happens if `cleveref` is omitted?  also, i've always gone by the principle that `hyperref` should almost always be loaded last, since its redefinitions of many "core" commands can be changed only at one's peril.  (not in a position where i can test anything now; can only make suggestions.)

Comment: If `cleveref` is omitted, everything works fine.  If I load `hyperref` after `cleveref`, then I get a different error: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167849/how-do-i-use-aliascnt-with-cleveref.

Comment: And if I do `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{cleveref}}`, then `htlatex` works fine.

Comment: that seems to be your answer.  go ahead and answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{cleveref}}`, to ensure that it is loaded after various packages.