# tex4ht: incompatibility of cleveref and amsthm?

Tags: tex4ht, cleveref, amsthm

I found that tex4ht doesn't work with cleveref and amsthm. I just modified the HWE from [an old post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220288/):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{rmk}\label{test}
Test content
\end{rmk}

See the test found in \cref{test}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with htlatex, it complains:

```
! Argument of \eorem:syle has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \begin{rmk}
               \label{test}
```

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167932/15172) suggests `\AtBeginDocument`. However, then the `\cref` will be rendered wrongly as `??`. I wonder a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Cleveref redefines lot of other macros and packages, which clashes with TeX4ht. It even adds an optional argument for `\refstepcounter`, which fails miserably with TeX4ht. So we need to redefine these redefined macros again and insert TeX4ht instructions that are necessary for it's referencing system to work.

First of all, we need to preserve the original version of `\refstepcounter`. This needs to be done before `cleveref.sty` is loaded. TeX4ht can modify the package loading using the `cleveref-hooks.4ht` file:

```
\let\HyOrg@addtoreset\@addtoreset
% fixes for \refstepcounter
\let\orig:refstepcounter\refstepcounter
\let\orig:@thm\@thm
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
\let\refstepcounter\orig:refstepcounter
\let\@thm\orig:@thm
}
```

We basically reset the modifications done to `\refstepcounter` by Cleveref. Next, we must add the support for the `\refstepcounter` optional argument and `amsthm` in `cleveref.4ht`:

```
% orig:refstepcounter is saved in cleveref-hooks.4ht
\let\cref@old@refstepcounter\orig:refstepcounter%
\def\refstepcounter{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\refstepcounter@optarg}{\refstepcounter@noarg}%]
}%

% fix for TeX4ht label mechanism
\def\cref:currentlabel#1{\let\cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
\def\:@currentlabel{\ifx \cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
   \expandafter\the\csname c@#1\endcsname\else \@currentlabel\fi}%
%
  \anc:lbl r{#1}%
}

\def\refstepcounter@noarg#1{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}
    \cref:currentlabel{#1}%
    }%
\def\refstepcounter@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#2}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#2}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#2}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#2\endcsname\csname the#2\endcsname}
    \cref:currentlabel{#2}%
  }%

\ifdefined\@firstoffive\else%
  \def\@firstoffive#1#2#3#4#5{#1}
\fi
\def\:tempa#1#2{\bgroup%
  \def\rEfLiNK##1##2{\Link{##1}{}}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoffive\csname r@#2\endcsname{}{}{}{}{}%
  \o:@@@setcref:{#1}{#2}%
  \EndLink\egroup%
}%

\HLet\@@@setcref=\:tempa

\@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{
  \let\cref@thmnoarg\@thm%
  \def\@thm{\@ifnextchar[{\cref@thmoptarg}{\cref@thmnoarg}}%]
  \def\:tempb[#1]#2#3#4{%
   % call original amsthm theorem definition, but
   % disable \:thm in order to prevent infinite loop
   \let\:thm\:gobble
   \cref@thmnoarg{#2}%
   \o:cref@thmoptarg:[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}
  }%
  \HLet\cref@thmoptarg\:tempb
}{}%


\Hinput{cleveref}

\endinput
```

With these fixes, the compilation works and creates a correct HTML:

[image]

Comment: A quick remark is that we also need to do with `\Cref`. And what about other environments (like `theorem`, `lemma`, `definition`, etc.)?

Comment: @Yai0Phah it uses low-level commands, so it should work for `\Cref` and all environments defined using `\newtheorem`